# jQuery AJAX script not firing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I have the following AJAX script which doesn't seem to be firing. Can anybody please tell me what's wrong with it?

**form.php**

```
<script type = "text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#updatebtn1').click(function () {
        $('#result1').show('slow').delay(4000).hide('slow')
        $.post('process.php', $('#updateform1').serialize())
    });
});
</script>

<form id="updateform1">
    <div class="tbl_header">Timetable Support Website</div>Due Date:
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
                minDate: -0,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                maxDate: new Date(2013, 1, 22)
            })
        });
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker1" style="width: 100px;
            height: 10px;" value="18/02/2013" name="duedate" />&nbsp; Status:
    <select style="width: 125px;" name="status">
        <option>Pending</option>
        <option>----</option>
        <option>Pending</option>
        <option>In Progress</option>
        <option>Complete</option>
    </select>&nbsp;
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
    <input type="button" id="updatebtn1" value="Update" style="width: 100px;"
    class="pmbtn" />
</form>
<div id="result1" style="display: none; color: red">Update successful!</div>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
$duedate = $_POST["duedate"];
$status = $_POST["status"];
$id = $_POST["id"];

$sql = "UPDATE pm_schedule SET duedate=?, status=?, id=? WHERE id=?";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($duedate,$status,$id));
?>
```

Comment: Don't use `mysql_real_escape_string` with PDO

Comment: How do you determine "not firing"?

Comment: @Mike the values in the database are not being updated

Comment: @Mike Database is connected as far as I'm concerned and field names used are correct - so I'm baffed as to why everything is not working

Comment: Can you check your browser console to see whether the request is sent to the server? Also try to put a console stmt in the update click handler to see whether it is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not overly familiar with positional place holders (I always used named place holders), but I'm assuming you need to do

```
$q->execute(array($duedate,$status,$id,$id));
```

since `$id` is used twice. MySQL doesn't know what you want for the final place holder. It's likely throwing some sort of error that the place holder count doesn't match.

Try adding this to your database handle:

```
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

and then echoing the output of `process.php` back to the main page.